# tableview size when switching to landscape iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

I have a UITableViewController with a table view that works perfectly when in portrait mode.

the problem is when IO rotate the phone the tableView won't scroll all the way through it keeps bouncing back. (have switched bounce scrolling off) I suspect the tableview size is not correct but I can't fibure out why this works for multiple tableviews in the app except this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the table view's `autoresizingMask` property is set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`, or manually set its frame to the fit its containing view in your view controller (you are using a view controller, right?)'s `-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method.

Comment: Thanks, it only does it on the sim when i checked the phone it works fine ??